# How to remove the setTimeout and use async await method in angular

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

If I removed the `setTimeout` form my below mentioned code then the blocks of code (getUnderlyingData) is running before the previous response. So I am not getting the proper response. Please anyone help me to resove this issue.
Current code:

```js
await this.TableauService.initViz(this.TableauViz, this.DataContainer, this.DataURL).then(([uniqData, TableauViz]) => {
    this.VizWorkbook = TableauViz;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.SheetData = this.TableauService.getUnderlyingData(TableauViz, "KPI",(response) => {
        console.log("sheet data",response);
      }); 
    },7000);
  });
}
```

Comment: Firstly, it's almost always wrong to mix `async`/`await` and `.then`. Secondly, create a helper for timeouts `const delay = async ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));`. This is one of the **_rare_** cases for using the promise constructor directly, when you are adapting a callback based API like `setTimeout`. Usage: `await delay(7000)`

Answer (score 0):

If you use `await` you don't need to use `then` to resolve the promise, `await` will do that for you.

An async function can contain an `await` expression that pauses the execution of the async function and waits for the passed promise's resolution after which it resumes the async function's execution and returns the resolved value.

```
async functionName(){
let result = await this.TableauService.initViz(this.TableauViz, this.DataContainer, this.DataURL)
}
```

The above `result`  variable holds your resolved value with that you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply add this line `this.VizWorkbook = TableauViz;` inside your `getUnderlyingData(.. {  this.VizWorkbook = TableauViz; ...  }`